# Alfresco share customization with maven SDK

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-maven

I am newbie to alfresco and my requirement is to make customization in existing modules (out-of-the-box) feature in alfresco,I trying to change in discussion forum with taking Alfresco Maven SDK.

So please anyone tell me that is that I am going on right track or not? Is it possible with maven SDK or not? and know me if there is any other easy option is available.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But your question is unclear. Which existing module do you want to change? How? Which files will be affected?

Comment: I want to make change in discussion module! want to add some new fields.

Comment: @LutzHorn - I am using AIO sdk and used mvn install to generate both share.war and repo.war but I not able to understand where I need to replace them in alfresco community source to see those changes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Bhaumik , yes you can use SDK to change discussion module,after that create .amp file of share and repo and deploy it into community.

Comment: @SanjayPatel Thanks for your response.